# how to validate images in PHP properly?

Tags: php, validation, file-upload

I am not getting what i want,

Here is My Code :

```
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != "") { /* Main IF statement starts Here */

    $fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);

    $fileExt = end($kaboom);

    list ($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
    if ($width < 10 || $height < 10) {
        header("Location: a.php?err=2");
        exit();
    }

    $db_file_name = rand(100000000000, 999999999999) . "." . $fileExt;

    if ($fileSize > 1048576) {
        header("Location: a.php?err=3");
        exit();
    } 

    elseif (! preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName)) {
        header("Location: a.php?err=4");
        exit();
    } 

    elseif ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        header("Location: a.php?err5");
        exit();
    }
}  /* Main IF statement ends Here */

else {
    header("Location: go_back.php?err=2");
    exit();
}
```

Width and height validations are working properly, but `if ($fileSize > 1048576)` filesize is greater than 1MB then it redirects me to `go_back.php?err=2` and I want it to redirect to `a.php?err=3`

Comment: Try some debug, what do you get when you echo $fileSize?

Comment: i did't tried that @SameerJain

Comment: You should check the mime type to validate that is a image! Verify the name is a very weak validation.

Comment: If you get `err=2`, then obviously `$width` and/or `$height` are not set as expected.

Comment: I guess `getimagesize($fileTmpLoc)` returns `false` and some `E_WARNING` or `E_NOTICE` are presented.

Comment: Nice try looking at `getimagesize`, `width`, `height` etc., but if you get redirected to `go_back.php?err=2`, then the first `if` statement has already failed! -- `if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != "")`. So the question is, what's wrong with the upload of >1MB files itself? Does your PHP upload size limit allow this to begin with?

Comment: thanks! and i know that but how can i solve that @Guido

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi Did you already check the PHP `upload_max_filesize` configuration settings. On most servers, it's set to only 2MB by default! See also https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:uploadsize for more instructions depending on which server you're running.

Comment: @Guido bro there is already a validation for file size. The problem is in main if statement :(

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi If the PHP-internal filesize validation fails, then the script will never reach the point where you try to validate the size yourself. The upload itself will already fail and `$_FILES["avatar"]` array information will not be assigned, and therefore your main `if` statement will fail – which is what I suspect is happening right now.

Comment: @Guido in my php.ini file the upload_max_filesize is 2M, what should i do now ?

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi My suggestion is to increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to a larger value (e.g. 15M) and see what happens. If my theory is correct, then the `ìf` statement should succeed.